# ¿Como validar que un input no venga con saltos en linea (espacios en blanco) en PHP?

Tags: php

Ya se que puedo utilizar `empty($valor)` para determinar si mi variable está vacía.
Lo peligroso de esto es que si alguien manda en el input puros caracteres en blanco (con la barra espaciadora) asumirá que no esta vacía.

Entonces

> ¿cómo puedo detectar si solo vienen caracteres en blanco en un input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Además de la función que mencionas `empty()` puedes valerte de `trim()` que esta destinada para:

> Eliminar espacios al inicio y al final de una cadena.

Ejemplo: Tenemos esta cadena que tiene espacios vacíos dentro de si y con la función empty() nos indica que posee valores aunque estos son solo *espacios en blanco*

```
$variable = "    ";

echo (empty($variable) ? 0 : 1);
```

Lo anterior retorna 1.

Ahora si conjuntamos el uso de `empty` con el uso de `trim()` del modo siguiente:

```
$variable = "    ";

echo (empty(trim($variable)) ? 0 : 1);
```

Nos retorna 0 con lo cual nos indica que si se encuentra vacía

Lo anterior es válido incluso si le pasamos un valor en texto con espacios en blanco al inicio, pues se los elimina:

```
$variable = "   valor en texto";

echo (empty(trim($variable)) ? 0 : 1);
```

Nos retorna 1

- Función `trim()` https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php